# what is difference between pre-measure and measure?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a important question. in the book of real analysis by **Folland**, measure on a $\sigma$-algebra is Defined and pre-measure on a algebra. But in the book of real analysis by **Aliprantis** measure on a **semiring** is Defined. what is difference  between this two Definition? thanks

Comment: From comparing both of the definitions it seems that they are some what equivalent, just don't quote me on that 100%.  I looked up both of the definitions of a $\sigma$-algebra and a semiring (of sets) and the third condition for a semiring essentially says that the collection $S$ of sets is closed under complements and countable unions. Here's the link I took for each definition. For semirings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring (scroll down to semirings for sets) and for sigma algebras: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

A consequence of starting with an algebra or semiring is the different definitions of a **premeasure**, which can be extended to a measure.

If you start with an algebra (e.g. Folland, Stein), then a premeasure $\mu$ needs to satisfy **countable additivity**, i.e. for $E_1 , E_2 , \dots$ in the algebra that are disjoint,
$$
  \mu \left( \bigcup _{k = 1} ^\infty E_k \right) 
  = \sum _{k = 1} ^\infty \mu(E_k).
$$
On the other hand, starting from a semiring (e.g. Aliprantis, Fitzpatrick), $\mu$ is only required to be **finitely additive** and **countably monotone** (or countably subadditive), i.e. for $E_1 , \dots, E_n$ in the semiring that are disjoint,
$$
  \mu \left( \bigcup _{k =1} ^n E_k \right) 
  = \sum _{k = 1} ^n\mu(E_k),
$$
and if $E \subset \bigcup _{k = 1} ^\infty E_k$ where every set is in the semiring, then
$$
  \mu (E)
  \leq \sum _{k = 1} ^\infty \mu(E_k).
$$

An algebra is a semiring. One can also show that countable additivity and monotonicity together implies countable monotonicity. Thus in conclusion, a weaker set structure requires stronger assumptions on the premeasure, and vice versa.